# Why CXF rest web service returns object if only one object in ArrayList?

Tags: web-services, rest, cxf

When a list has only one object, CXF rest web service return the object instead JSON array. Its working fine for more than one object. Could you please help me to solve this.

For two objects in list JSON response is

```
{
 "list": [
{
  "@xsi.type": "interaction",
  "interactionId": 92009,
  "interactionTitle": "How are you? How is going?",
  "interactionType": "Question"
},
{
  "@xsi.type": "interaction",
  "interactionId": 92004,
  "interactionTitle": "This is not working",
  "interactionType": "Complaint"
}
],
 "message": "Request successfully processed",
 "totalRecords": 5,
 "statusCode": 2000
}
```

For one record in list JSON response is

```
{
 "list": {
 "@xsi.type": "interaction",
 "interactionId": 92009,
 "interactionTitle": "How are you? How is going?",
 "interactionType": "Question"
},
"message": "Request successfully processed",
"totalRecords": 5,
"statusCode": 2000
}
```

I am expecting JSON array in both cases. But its returning JSON object instead on JSON Array for single object.

Here I am using Apache CXF rest framework to expose web services.

Here is server side code sample

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/interactions")
public VerveResponse<Interaction> getUserInteractions(){
    VerveResponse<Interaction> verveResponse = new VerveResponse<Interaction>();
    verveResponse.setStatusCode(""+StatusCode.PROCESSED_SUCCESSFULLY);
    verveResponse.setMessage("Request successfully processed");
    List<Interaction> interactionList = ExternalService.getInteractionList();
    verveResponse.setList(interactionList);
    return verveResponse;
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlSeeAlso({Interaction.class})
public class VerveResponse<T> implements Serializable{
    private String statusCode;
    private String message;
    private List<T> list;
    private Long records;

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getRecords() {
        return records;
    }
    public void setRecords(Long records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }   
}

  @XmlRootElement(name = "interaction")
  public class Interaction implements Serializable {
     private Long interactionId;
     private String interactionTitle;
     private String interactionType;

    public Long getInteractionId() {
       return interactionId;
     }
    public void setInteractionId(Long interactionId) {
        this.interactionId = interactionId;
    }
    public String getInteractionTitle() {
      return interactionTitle;
    }
    public void setInteractionTitle(String interactionTitle) {
     this.interactionTitle = interactionTitle;
    }
   public String getInteractionType() {
     return interactionType;
   }
   public void setInteractionType(String interactionType) {
     this.interactionType = interactionType;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should add some code; otherwise, it's almost impossible to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a list has only one element, CXF return the object instead a js array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918091/when-a-list-has-only-one-element-cxf-return-the-object-instead-a-js-array)

Comment: @MGorgon Yes.. its duplicate... Solution provided in that thread not working for me & Sikorski(The person who answered that question) asked me to post new question. You can find my comment in that thread